# OH-TFS-Connector-0051: InvalidNotEmpty for field [Remaining Work] value [0]

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I am migrating my team projects from *"on premises"* TFS Server 2013 to Visual Studio Team Services online using OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility v.2.2.8.000.

In a team project, in particular, I am getting this error:

> OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed createOrUpdateEntity. Server
>   Error : Failed to create/update entity because :      InvalidNotEmpty for
>   field [Remaining Work] value [0]

Anybody know how to resolve this?

---

I transcribe below the log work item changes. The changes of 2 days ago were attempts to workaround the problem.
Note that there are several changes in value for the 'Remaining Work' field, well as 'Original Estimate' and 'Completed Work'.
i just don't understand why I get this error during the migration.

```
    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                 made field changes (a day ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   13                                          12
    Remaining Work                                                    1
    Original Estimate                                                 2
    Completed Work                                                    2

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                  made field changes (2 days ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   12                                          11
    Remaining Work        1                                           0


    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                  made field changes (2 days ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   11                                          10
    Remaining Work        0
    Completed Work        2

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                   made field changes (2 days ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   10                                          9
    Remaining Work                                                    0

    Israel Guilherme de Oliveira Ferreira   added comment, added link, made other changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   9                                           8

    Israel Guilherme de Oliveira Ferreira   made field changes(4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   8                                           7
    Remaining Work        0                                           2

    Israel Guilherme de Oliveira Ferreira   changed state from Active to Closed, made field changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    State                 Closed                                      Active
    Rev                   7                                           6
    Reason                Completed                                   Reactivated
    State Change Date     quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 17:30:45  quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 17:29:49
    Closed Date           quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 17:30:45
    Closed By             Israel Guilherme de Oliveira Ferreira

    Israel Guilherme de Oliveira Ferreira   changed state from Closed to Active, made field changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    State                 Active                                      Closed
    Rev                   6                                           5
    Reason                Reactivated                                 Completed
    State Change Date     quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 17:29:49  quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 10:53:10
    Activated Date        quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 17:29:49  terça-feira, 24 de abril de 2012 10:36:03
    Activated By          Israel Guilherme de Oliveira Ferreira       Eric Nazário Cordeiro
    Closed Date           quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 10:53:10
    Closed By             Eric Nazário Cordeiro

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                    changed state from Active to Closed, added comment, made other changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    State                 Closed                                      Active
    Rev                   5                                           4
    Reason                Completed                                   New
    State Change Date     quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 10:53:10  terça-feira, 24 de abril de 2012 10:36:03
    Closed Date           quinta-feira, 26 de abril de 2012 10:53:10
    Closed By             Eric Nazário Cordeiro

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                    added comment, added link, made other changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   4                                           3

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                    made field changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   3                                           2
    Assigned To           Eric Nazário Cordeiro

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                    made field changes (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value                                   Old value
    Rev                   2                                           1
    Remaining Work        2

    Eric Nazário Cordeiro                    created the Task (4 years ago)
    Fields
    Field                 New value
    Iteration Path        Catraca\Sprint 1
    Iteration ID          50
    Team Project          Catraca
    Node Name             Business
    Area Path             Catraca\Business
    Area ID               55
    Title                 Implementar classes de negócio
    State                 Active
    Rev                   1
    Reason                New
    Work Item Type        Task
    Created Date          terça-feira, 24 de abril de 2012 10:36:03
    Created By            Eric Nazário Cordeiro
    Description           Implementar classes de negócio
    Activity              Development
    Priority              1
    State Change Date     terça-feira, 24 de abril de 2012 10:36:03
    Activated Date        terça-feira, 24 de abril de 2012 10:36:03
    Activated By          Eric Nazário Cordeiro
    Original Estimate     2
```

Comment: Can you share the error trace from 'C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs\OpsHubTFSService.log' Can you also look for that particular work item in source and see what history audits exists and in which one of those was the 'Remaining Work' field changes? (The failure details in the UI of the tool should point you to the WIT's ID)

Comment: Based on the log, the Remaining work and Completed work have no value, what's the result if you change them and try to migrate?

Comment: @starain, I tried that. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: What's team project template of source team project? You can try to destroy that work item, then migrate work item and check the result.